# Getting an empty string when scanned

Tags: graph, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to create a Graph from a file input. The first line of the file contains an int and the second line in the file contains either a D or a U for directed and undirected. But when I did some troubleshooting to try and find the error in my code I found that my Scanner was scanning the second line as an empty string instead of the letter D. Here's my code. I rewrote the file so I know the file isn't wrong.

The file is:

```
7
D
(0, 1)
(0, 3)
.
.
.
```

Code:

```
public static Graph createFromFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    int line1 = scan.nextInt();
    vertexCount = line1;
    System.out.println(vertexCount);

    String line2 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line2);
    String linne2 = "\"" + line2 + "\"";
    System.out.println(linne2);
    if(linne2.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){directed = true;}
    else if(linne2.equalsIgnoreCase("U")){directed = false;}
    else{System.out.println("This is not the proper input");}
}
```

The output is:

```
7

""
This is not the proper input
```

Does anybody know where this issue is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scan.nextInt function doesn't take the execution to next line. So, scan.nextLine call is still on your first line and it returns rest of the data from first line , which in this case is basically space. Use one more scan.nextLine and it will give you expected result. 
Also , please go through the documentation of Scanner class , it will clear your doubts

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. I'll check out the Scanner class.